# Map an Integer to a percentage [0,100]

Tags: java, casting, int, double, percentage

I am trying to map all the `Integer`s in the range `[0.0, 100.0]`.

I know that the formula is:

```
((input - min) * 100) / (max - min)
```

You can imagine that if you want to map the entire `Integer` domain you will have to use `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

```
double percentage = ((double) input - Integer.MIN_VALUE) * 100 / (Integer.MAX_VALUE - Integer.MIN_VALUE);
```

The problem here is that `Integer.MAX_VALUE - Integer.MIN_VALUE` will overflow to `-1`.

The solution I came up with is to convert every `Integer` to a `double` before doing any operation

```
double percentage = ((double) input - (double) Integer.MIN_VALUE) * 100.0 / ((double) Integer.MAX_VALUE - (double) Integer.MIN_VALUE);
```

Some of the cast to a `double` can be omitted but for clarity I will leave all of them.

Is there a better and cleaner way to do this mapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleaner way :

```
Double input = 12d;
Double min = Double.valueOf(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
Double max = Double.valueOf(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

Double percentage = (input - min)*100.0/(max-min);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the easiest approach which allows you use the first formula and do the subtraction in the integer domain, is to cast the inputs to `long`, which has enough bits to represent the result of the subtraction exactly. I'm not sure I'd consider that "cleaner", though. In practice, casting the inputs to `double` is probably the least surprising and most practical approach.

Answer (score -2):

First thing: you cannot do it without casting, otherwise you will have integer division, which you probably won't want, even if it wasn't is such extreme case. So, casting is unavoidable for correctness in regular cases. In this case this need is enforced by the overflow, but the overflow alone does not justify using floating point. Long could be an option if overflow was the only issue.

Second: it is enough to cast only one element in your formula per expression, the others will be casted to perform this operation.

Example:
This is redundant

`(double) input - (double) Integer.MIN_VALUE`

It is the same as

```
(double) input - Integer.MIN_VALUE
```

So, just by removing the redundancies you have

```
((double) input - Integer.MIN_VALUE) * 100 / ((double) Integer.MAX_VALUE - Integer.MIN_VALUE)
```

If you like it short and the code is simple, you may import statically (this is more a matter of opinion though)

```
import static java.lang.Integer.MIN_VALUE;
import static java.lang.Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

This transforms the same line of your formula into:

```
((double) input - MIN_VALUE) * 100 / ((double) MAX_VALUE - MIN_VALUE)
```

You also can consider the following as final variables:

> final Double PERCENTAGE_COEF = 100 / ((double) MAX_VALUE - MIN_VALUE);
>
> final Double RANGE_SIZE = (double) MAX_VALUE - MIN_VALUE;

Finally you could have in the end

```
delta * PERCENTAGE_COEF
```

For instance, if this is to be used in a reusable for, you could choose a better name than mine, you would have something like:

```
final static Double PERCENTAGE_COEF = 100 / ((double) MAX_VALUE - MIN_VALUE);

public Double apply( Double input) {
    double delta = input - MIN_VALUE;
    return delta * PERCENTAGE_COEF ;
}
```

All those changes are a matter of taste though. For performance, your compiler will probably guess the constants anyway.

Comment: You need to cast because of overflow, not because of integer division. Nothing really wrong with inter division here.

Comment: I said you need casting. And yes it if due to both reasons. Try using this formular out of this extreme case...

Comment: Or just try with longs